# Combinatorics - rewriting generating function as power series

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, power-series, generating-functions

I have been working on the following question:

Find a recurrence relation for the number of regions created by $n$ mutually intersecting circles on a piece of paper (no three circles have a common intersecting point). Then, show using the generating function that
$$a_n = n^2 - n +2$$
for $n \ge 1$.

I have found
$$a_n = a_{n-1} + 2(n-1)$$
with $a_1 = 2$.
I have also found that the generating function is
$$f(x) = \frac{2x^3-2x^2+2x}{(1-x)^3}.$$
Now, I just have to rewrite it to the power series, but I can't seem to get the right result. Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This can also be resolved using the usual formula for sums of consecutive integers: $$\begin{align}
a_{n+1}
&= a_{n} + 2n\\
&=a_{n-1}+2(n-1)+2n\\
&=\cdots \\&=a_1+2(1+2+\cdots + n)\\
&=2+n(n-1)
\end{align}
$$
But presumably they want you to practice using generating functions.

Answer (score 1):

Applying partial fraction decomposition yields
\begin{align}
\frac{2x^3-2x^2+2x}{(1-x)^3}
&= -2 + \frac{4}{1-x} - \frac{4}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{2}{(1-x)^3} \\
&= -2 + 4\sum_{n \ge 0} x^n - 4 \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n+1}{1} x^n + 2 \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n+2}{2} x^n \\
&= -2x^0 + \sum_{n \ge 0} \left(4 - 4 \binom{n+1}{1} + 2 \binom{n+2}{2}\right) x^n,
\end{align}
which immediately implies that
\begin{align}
a_n 
&= -2[n=0] + 4 - 4 \binom{n+1}{1} + 2 \binom{n+2}{2} \\
&= -2[n=0]+n^2-n+2 \\
&= \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if $n=0$} \\ n^2-n+2 &\text{if $n>0$} \end{cases}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{\frac{2x^3-2x^2+2x}{(1-x)^3}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-3}{2}(-x)^n\tag{1}\\
> &\quad=\left(2x^3-2x^2+2x\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+2}{2}x^n\tag{2}\\
> &\quad=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(n+2)\left(x^{n+3}-x^{n+2}+x^{n+1}\right)\\
> &\quad=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(n-2)(n-1)x^n-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)nx^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(n+1)x^n\tag{3}\\
> &\quad=\sum_{n=3}\left((n-2)(n-1)-(n-1)n+n(n+1)\right)x^n\\
> &\quad\qquad+\left(2\cdot 3-1\cdot 2\right)x^2+2x\\
> &\quad=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\left(n^2-n+2\right)x^n+4x^2+2x\\
> &\quad\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(n^2-n+2\right)x^n}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we multiply out and shift the indices to get terms with $x^n$.